# pyqt5 splashscreen to start parallel to QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsplashscreen

My pyqt5 Application which I compiled into .exe takes longer to start. I wanted to use Qsplaschscreen to inform the user that the program is loading so that the user does not end up clicking more than necessary on the application. I have challenges calling the Qsplaschscreen.I noticed it delays similar to the time it takes for the Mainwindow to start.

What I wanted is that the Qsplaschscreen should be immediate and should be called at the same time as the Qmainwindow. And then it should close immediately the mainwindow becomes visible

This is a snippet of my implementation.

```
class SplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
    close_signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(QPixmap(""))

        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(16)

        self.text_label = QLabel("Loading...", self)
        self.text_label.setFont(self.font)
        self.text_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.text_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
        self.text_label.move(0, self.size().height() - 50)
        self.text_label.adjustSize()
        self.text_label.show()
```

Then I call the main window in this formart.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    splash = SplashScreen()
    splash.show()

    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = myWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It may be necessary to understand *what* makes the program take so much time to start: if the compiled exe uses the single file option and the archive contains a lot of files, there's almost nothing you can do, because the problem exists way before the script has even started; if you're using pyinstaller, it supports an [experimental splash screen](https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#splash-screen-experimental).

Comment: Thnaks a lot @musicamante. I used pyinstaller and compiled into a single file. I will check the experimental splash screen and see. I really appreciate your intput